# In C, how do I make a string with non-static duration time?

Tags: c, string

I have a string, that is only used once when my application launches. Ordinary string literals, eg. `"Hello"` are static, meaning they're only deallocated when the program ends. I don't want that. They can be deallocated earlier. How do I say, Hey, like, this string literal shouldn't be static. It should be deallocated when the scope ends. How do I do that? For example,

```
memcpy(GameDir+HomeDirLen, "/.Data", 7);
```

The `"/.Data"` is still stored in ram as the literal even long after the this line of code runs. That's a waste, because it's only used once.

Comment: Declare a char array on the stack? Or `malloc`/`calloc` a region of memory for a string?

Comment: @PiRocks How do I declare a string on the stack?

Comment: `char string[MAX_LEN];`

Comment: I'm curious why you care about wasting 7 characters of ram though.

Comment: In the big scheme of things, the space "wasted" by these literal strings is really to small to bother with most of the time. Even on computers thirty years ago (when main memory was commonly counted in **kilo**bytes) it usually wasn't an issue.

Comment: @PiRocks Or better `char string[] = "/.Data";` to not *waste* unused bytes in the array. :)

Comment: Following up to what @PiRocks said, I believe if you do `char string[MAX_LEN] = "hello";`, the string won't be stored in the read-only section but only in the executable code.

Comment: @PiRocksd Even though 7 bytes isn't much, it builds for other strings.

Comment: @PiRocks....8051 :)

Comment: Unless you write a text-adventure where all text and strings are literal strings inside the executable, literal strings is usually a very minor part of the executable and in-memory image of the program. Have you actually *measured* that this is a top memory hog of your program? Also remember that most C compilers usually only store *one* of each string literal, so if you have `"/.Debug"` in multiple places, only one instance of that string will be stored in your program.

Comment: The answers show you two ways to create strings that have automatic storage duration (compound literals and an array of `char`). But both, as shown in those answers, are initialized with a string. By necessity, that string must be in your program too, and it is not deallocated.

Comment: How about `long long magic = 0x5F236BAFull * 0xDF578581ull; printf((char*)&magic);`

Answer (score 5):

With typical implementations, if your program contains the string `"/.Data"` anywhere, either as a literal or as an initializer for an array of any duration, then the program is going to contain those bytes somewhere in the executable.  They'll be loaded (or mapped) into memory when the program loads, and I don't know of any implementation that can free such memory before the program exits.  So the other answers so far don't really accomplish what you want.

(If your array was of auto duration, then initializing is typically done under the hood by copying from an anonymous static string.  Or it could be done by a sequence of immediate store instructions, which probably uses even *more* memory.)

So if you really want to ensure that those bytes don't occupy memory for the life of the process, you'll have to get them from somewhere other than the program itself.  For instance, you could store the string in a file, open it, and read the string into an `auto` or `malloc`ed array.  Then you really will recover the memory when the array goes out of scope or is `free`d (assuming, of course, that `free` actually does recover memory in a way that's useful to you).  You could also use `mmap` if your system provides it.

On the other hand, modern operating systems usually have virtual memory.  So if your string literal is in the read-only data section of the program, then if physical memory becomes tight, the system can simply drop that page of physical memory and use it for something else.  If your program should attempt to access that data again, the system will allocate a new page and transparently populate it from the executable file on disk - but if you never access it, that will never happen.

Of course this doesn't help much if your string is really only 7 bytes, because there will be lots of other stuff in that page of memory (a page is commonly 4KB or somewhere around there).  But if your string is really big, or you have a lot of such strings, then this effect may work just as well as actually freeing the memory.  You may even be able to use various compiler-specific options to ensure that all your only-needed-once strings are placed contiguously in the executable, so that they will all be in the same pages of memory.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a string, that is only used once when my application launches.
>   Ordinary string literals, eg. `"Hello"` are static, meaning they're only
>   deallocated when the program ends. I don't want that. They can be
>   deallocated earlier. How do I say, Hey, like, this string literal
>   shouldn't be static. It should be deallocated when the scope ends. How
>   do I do that?

You cannot.  All string literals have static storage duration, and that's really the only way they could work.  If you have a string literal in your program source that is used in any way, then the program image has to contain the bytes of the literal's representation somewhere among the program data.  If the literal appears inside a function, as must be the case in your example, then the representation needs to be retained for use each time the function is called.  Similar applies to uses at file scope: string literals used there typically are accessible for the entire run of the program.

The exception is string literals used as initializers for (other) character arrays with static storage duration.  Such an initialization results in, initially, two identical copies of the same data, at most one of which is actually accessible at run time.  There's no use for retaining the data for the literal separately.  C does not specify a way for you to express that the literal should not be retained, but your compiler is at liberty to omit the unneeded duplicate at its own discretion, and at least some do.

Compilers may also fold identical string literals, and perhaps even fold literals that just have identical tails, and / or perform other space-saving optimizations.  And your compiler is likely to be better than you are at recognizing when and how such optimizations can safely be performed.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not really match your specific need. I'll leave it for the comments.

<strike>You can use a [compound literal](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5) ... and a pointer to it</strike>

```
char *p = (char[]){"Hello!"}; // vs char *p = "Hello!"
*p = 'C';                     //    *p = 'C'; // illegal
```

see https://ideone.com/62UNKO

Comment: But will this: `memcpy(GameDir+GameDirLen, (const char[]){"./Data"}, 7);` work?

Comment: If you are using the compound literal for one time assignment (your memcpy) no need to save it.

Comment: yes, that will work (the `const` looks odd, like `x += (const int)42;`)

Comment: This will typically still result in the literal string `"Hello!"` being stored in memory for the whole duration of the program.  It had to be somewhere before the anonymous array came into scope, so that it could be used to initialize that array, and typically there is no provision for freeing it afterwards.  So this is probably actually *worse*, in terms of running time and memory usage, than `static char p[] = "Hello!";`

Comment: @NateEldredge: doesn't C11 2.5.6.5p5 apply here? "... has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block."

Comment: @pmg Yes, the compound literal has automatic storage duration, but the actual string literal `"Hello!"` is treated like any other string literal. It gets copied into the compound literal when the compound literal is created. Check the assembly code, and you should see something like *L_.str:   .asciz "Hello!"*

Comment: Well, it moves it into the code segment. https://godbolt.org/z/SzvB39

Comment: The storage duration only limits when the *program* can safely use the data.  What the implementation actually does behind the scenes is a completely different story, and the standard has nothing to say about that, so long as correct programs still run.

Comment: @FredLarson So, does this means that if this compound string is used more than once it will use even more memory as there will be several copies of the same string loaded in memory as code segments?

Comment: @isrnick: Perhaps. BTW, I switched the compiler to MSVC and it used the same code as `char* p = "Hello!";` -- static string. And it used one for each example, even though the string literal is identical in each case.

Comment: Why are you basically suiciding your answer?

Comment: My answer keeps a copy of the string around, something I was trying to avoid. The comments, however, are good so there is enough relevant information to make me feel it's wrong to delete the answer (and comments).